# How to set constant property of a matlab class via a matlab function?

Tags: matlab, function, class, oop, simulink

according to the example of [Mathworks-Static Data Documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-data.html) I'd like to know how I can set the constant property 'Data1' via a matlab function out of simulink (matlab function as an interface to simulink).

```
classdef SharedData < handle
   properties 
      Data1
      Data2
   end
end
```

and

```
classdef UseData
   properties (Constant)
      Data = SharedData
   end
   ...
end
```

Function in Simulink:

```
function O = fcn(I)
    ...
    i.Data.Data1 = I;
    O = i.Data.Data1;
end
```

Within matlab command window the function looks good, but when I start the simulation in simulink there is obviously a problem with setting constants via the function.

**Does somebody know how I can set the constants from a matlab function so I can use this function as an interface to simulink I/Os?**

Thank you

Comment: If you're changing it externally, it doesn't seem like a *constant*...

Comment: I totally agree, but it seems it's a common way (see link above) to use the same properties from several classes..

Comment: What do you mean by "the function looks good"? when run from the Command Window.  Accorind to the link you give "The only way to change the value of a constant property is to change the class definition. ", which would seem to say that you can't change the value as you are trying to do.

Comment: Sry, I mean the functionALITY of the classes and global changes of properties are working when they will be called from the command window. I fear that the topic can be closed but thank you for your helpfulness.